# Oauth2 Client ID Matching with Wrong Project

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have two separate Google App Engine projects (let's call them projects A and B) that I'm using Oauth2 to validate users for. For each project, I generated its own Oauth 2.0 Client ID.

So for project B, attempting to verify my Oauth2 token yields a value error. From what I can tell, for some reason it's expecting the ClientID from project A. Using project A's Client ID actually makes everything work as expected, which seems weird.

I'm using Python3.5 for this project and trying to use to deploy a webpage using Flask, if that helps anything.

Error Code: (keys redacted)

```
Token has wrong audience <Client ID A>, expected <Client ID B>
```

Code for verifying token:

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests as goog_requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
...
# Verify and get info for the user's ID token.
# This is where the error gets thrown
idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
    request.headers.get('X-id-token'),
    goog_requests.Request(),
    CLIENT_ID
)
```

Additional info - as I'd expect with that error code, the UI for loging in indicates that I'm trying to login to project A as well. I'm also wondering if this has anything to do with my google sdk cli configuration. I tried resetting my default project to project B but that didn't change anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I realized I mis-wrote the error code. It's fixed now. I guess the 'X-id-token' header is generating a token for project A instead of project B. Still new to web development generally, so I guess I'll try and figure out what's up with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumb. I didn't change the sign-in object(?) in my HTML to match the new Client ID. I had to change

```
<meta name="google-signin-client-id" content="CLIENT_ID">
```

to the new client ID.